# GDB instruction pointer

Tags: gdb, virtual-memory

This is the GDB output of the command info frame;

```
Stack level 1, frame at 0x7fff5fbffba0
rip = 0x100000ee4 in main (scc150_ex5.c:9);
   saved rip 0x100000eb4
caller of frame at 0x7fff5fbffb80
source language c.
Arglist at 0x7fff5fbffb98, args:
   Locals at 0x7fff5fbffb98,
Previous frame's sp is 0x7fff5fbffba0
Saved registers: rbp at 0x7fff5fbffb90,
   rip at 0x7fff5fbffb98
```

I am confused as to where the instruction pointer is saved, would it be at `0x100000eb4`? Also if this instruction pointer was to be overwritten unintentionally, would it just "mess" up the whole program? (I apologize for the use of mess).

Thanks

Comment: `gdb` tells you where `rip` is saved: "Saved registers: rbp at 0x7fff5fbffb90, rip at 0x7fff5fbffb98"

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused as to where the instruction pointer is saved, would it be at 0x100000eb4

No. It is saved at `0x7fff5fbffb98`. The *value* saved there is `0x100000eb4`.

> Also if this instruction pointer was to be overwritten unintentionally, would it just "mess" up the whole program?

Depends on what you mean by "mess up the whole program".

Overwriting saved location with e.g. `NULL` will cause your program to crash when it returns from `main`.